# How can I bet against a particular stock in relation to the market?

Tags: options, trading, stock-markets, option-strategies

I’ve heard people doing spread trades when they think one stock will do better/worse *in comparison to* another stock or index. I’m looking for details on exactly how this is done.

Is there a particular trading mechanism that would allow for:

Make money if X stock goes down in relation to e.g. S&P 500?

I would also add that I’d like the losses to be limited to the amount of investment (not unlimited) in case X outperforms the market.

Ideally looking for a way to trade where I would make money if X goes down even if the entire market / S&P 500 also goes down, as long as X goes down more (probably in terms of %)

Is this possible? Specifics of mechanics appreciated.

Comment: Related: [How do I bet one stock will outperform another stock?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/27625/how-do-i-bet-one-stock-will-outperform-another-stock), [Options strategy that profits from outperformance (or underperformance) relative to a stock index](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/131204/options-strategy-that-profits-from-outperformance-or-underperformance-relative)

Comment: You say "Ideally looking for a way to trade where I would make money if X goes down even if the entire market / S&P 500 also goes down," what's the motivation for having it tied to an index instead of just making a bearish bet against it?

Comment: As a general rule, in an up market, higher beta stocks go up more than the market does and drop more in poor markets.  It's the rule breakers that are painful.

Comment: @HartCO If it goes up because most stocks are going up due to inflation or low interest rates or whatever, I don’t want to lose money. I just want to bet that it’ll underperform the market.